# NameError: name 'dbutils' is not defined in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-blob-storage, databricks

I am running a pyspark job in databricks cloud. I need to write some of the csv files to databricks filesystem (dbfs) as part of this job and also i need to use some of the dbutils native commands like,

```
#mount azure blob to dbfs location
dbutils.fs.mount (source="...",mount_point="/mnt/...",extra_configs="{key:value}")
```

I am also trying to unmount once the files has been written to the mount directory. But, when i am using dbutils directly in the pyspark job it is failing with

```
NameError: name 'dbutils' is not defined
```

Should i import any of the package to use dbutils in pyspark code ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your code in Python notebook or are you submitting a plain python file?

Comment: @MartinWeber - My code is in plain python file.

Answer (score 28):

Try to use this:

```py
def get_dbutils(spark):
        try:
            from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils
            dbutils = DBUtils(spark)
        except ImportError:
            import IPython
            dbutils = IPython.get_ipython().user_ns["dbutils"]
        return dbutils

dbutils = get_dbutils(spark)
```

Comment: I tried this, and got this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.dbutils', and this from the except clause: KeyError: 'dbutils'

Comment: are you running on databricks? dbutils is not supported outside

Comment: Thank you! It was in an Azure Machine Learning VM.

Comment: Hi Elisabetta, thank you for this answer. It also helped me out a lot.

Comment: What is the parameter "spark" that you passed to the function?

Comment: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

Comment: How do I mount the azure storage in azure synapse notebook  ?

Comment: didn't work, I got `PicklingError: Could not serialize object: RuntimeError: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.`

Answer (score -6):

To access the `DBUtils` module in a way that works both locally and in `Azure Databricks clusters`, on Python, use the following `get_dbutils()`:

```
def get_dbutils(spark):
  try:
    from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils
    dbutils = DBUtils(spark)
  except ImportError:
    import IPython
    dbutils = IPython.get_ipython().user_ns["dbutils"]
  return dbutils
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-connect

Comment: While I appreciate the additional explanation and reference, it’s worth acknowledging that the code suggestion is an _exact_ duplicate of @Elisabetta‘s from a several months ago.

Answer (score -12):

yes!
You could use this:

```
pip install DBUtils
import DBUtils
```