# How to use dbutils command in pyspark job other than NoteBook

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to use dbutils command for accessing secrets in my pyspark job submitting through Spark-Submit inside Jobs on Databricks. While using dbutils command it is giving error dbutils not defined.

Is there is the way to use dbutils in a pyspark job other than a notebook?

Tried the following solutions:

1) import DBUtils, according to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52947713/11824257). But this is not Databricks dbutils.

2) import pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils , according to this [solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-connect#access-dbutils). But this also didn't work.

pyspark job as shown in below diagram:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3FEm.png)

Answer (score -1):

What I understand by your question- How do I access the secret value from the key-vault in Databricks notebook?
So to access the keys you have to link your Databricks notebook to the key-vault.
This linking has to be done by using the Scopes.
In the below url you have to provide the details:

https://westeurope.azuredatabricks.net/#secrets/createScope

If you open the link then you will land to a secret scope creation page:
[image: Scope creation Page]
Link may be vary depends on the area/region of subscription. In my case it is "westeurope".

You have to provide 3 values on the page:
**1)** Scope Name
**2)** DNS Name
**3)** Resource ID

Scope name have to be define manually and rest of the two values has to copy from the key-vault.
Now go to your Azure key-vault and click on **properties** section.
[image: KeyVaultScreenShot]

Copy the **DNS Name** and **Resource ID** values and paste it into required cells of the Scope creation page.

That's it. Now your notebook will point to your key vault.

I have given **az-kv-scope-test** name to my scope.

Lets assume my key-vault having a secret with the name **db_password** and I want to access it in my notebook.

So to access the secret value from the key vault inside the Databricks notebook I have to use the below command.

```
    // variable declaration and initialization.    
    val my_kv_scope = "az-kv-scope-test"    
    val password = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = my_kv_scope, key = "db_password")
```

Following link will guide you to get more information on secrete scopes.
https://docs.databricks.com/security/secrets/index.html

I hope this will give you some clarity on the Key-vault values accessibility in notebook.

Comment: Hi @venus, I want to use dbutils in a pyspark job, not in NoteBook. The pyspark job which we submit through spark-submit inside Jobs in Databricks. I attached the pyspark job in the question.

Comment: @Dheerajkumar Solanki - in that case, I do not have answer :(

Comment: @DheerajkumarSolanki were you able to find the solution?

Comment: No, till now I didn't find any solution for using dbutils in the spark-submit job in databricks

Comment: As of now `DBUtils` are not supported outside of Databricks notebooks.

Comment: please go through the databricks documentation `https://docs.databricks.com/jobs.html`