# Azure Databricks - Explain the mounting syntax in databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I am new to `azure` and `databricks`, I learned that how to mount blob and utilize but there are few doubts which I have and I did not found any answers to any documentation yet. So please help me to explain these:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
  extra_configs = {"<conf-key>":dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<scope-name>", key = "<key-name>")})
```

here  `"/mnt/<mount-name>"` refers to which location, is it some virtual file location which is used to mount and later use it.

Also, what is the need of `dbutils.secrets.get`.

If anyone can explain it will be great help to my learning.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding **mnt** is nothing but a virtual starting point of a directory.
**scope-name** is a way to connect with your key vault.
For example: https://westeurope.azuredatabricks.net/#secrets/createScope is link to create a scope
**key-name** is the secret name exist in your key-vault.

Please go through the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59176872/how-to-use-dbutils-command-in-pyspark-job-other-than-notebook/59220819#59220819) to get some details on this.

Answer (score 1):

Secrets allow you to store and access sensitive credential information without making them visible in notebooks.

**In simple words:**  To explain it clearly, I have used an example to mount an ADLS Gen2 without secrets and with secrets.

> Without secrets?

If you want to share Notebooks on the public forums like (Stackoverflow, MSDN, or GitHub), I need to blur the keys and share with you.

[image]

> With secrets?

I can share the Notebooks on the public forums without any modifications.

[image]

Reference: "[Azure Databricks - Secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/#secrets-user-guide)".

Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries.

---

Do click on "Mark as Answer" and Upvote on the post that helps you, this can be beneficial to other community members.