# Pyspark with DBUtils

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to use DBUtils and Pyspark from a jupyter notebook python script (running on Docker) to access an Azure Data Lake Blob.  However, I can't seem to get dbutils to be recognized (i.e. NameError: name 'dbutils' is not defined).  I've tried explicitly importing DBUtils, as well as not importing it as I read:

"An important point to remember is to never run import dbutils in your Python script. This command succeeds but clobbers all the commands so nothing works. It is imported by default." [Link](https://datathirst.net/blog/2018/11/30/pyspark-applications-for-databricks)

I've also tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50813493/nameerror-name-dbutils-is-not-defined-in-pyspark), but it still threw "KeyError: 'dbutils'"

```
spark.conf.set('fs.azure.account.key.<storage account>.blob.core.windows.net', <storage account access key>)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization", "true")
dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://<container>@<storage account>.dfs.core.windows.net/")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization", "false")
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

`dbutil` is only supported within databricks. To access the blob storage from non-databricks spark environments like a VM on Azure or HDI-Spark you need to modify the `core-site.xml` file. Here is a quick [guide](https://medium.com/@ArsenVlad/accessing-azure-storage-blobs-from-spark-1-6-that-is-running-locally-2739955c235d) for a stand-alone spark environment.

Comment: Is there a way to copy a file to dbfs without dbutils? dbutils.fs.cp("file:/source", "dbfs:/destination")