# Custom function in another Databricks Notebook gives NameError: name 'DBUtils' is not defined

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have a function that uses dbutils and get following error when I try to call the function with import:

NameError: name 'DBUtils' is not defined

I tried with following code:

```
def access_storage_acccount(
service_credential_key = "client-secret",
secretscopename = "key",
storage_account = "dlsdevhr",
key_dir_id = "tenant-id",
key_app_id = "client-id"):


directory_id = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = f"{secretscopename}", key = key_dir_id)
```

I have tried following solution in my function but it does not work [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50813493/nameerror-name-dbutils-is-not-defined-in-pyspark)

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: How do you include this notebook? as `%run` or as just normal `import` statement?

Comment: @AlexOtt I use `import`

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding below import statement in the notebook which you are trying to import

```
from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils
```